# Using function for two div or more

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My issue is that some of my div scripts work and others do not ! 
I've made a function with `JavaScript` that contains some mistakes.
I'm wondering what is my error. It's the same code, I've just copied and pasted it twice in different classes. Here is my code

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var cls = document.getElementById('showhide').className;
    $("#showhide").click(function () {
        $("#" + cls).show();
        $("#showhide").hide();
    });
    $("#cancel").click(function () {
        $("#" + cls).hide();
        $("#showhide").show();
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <div id='showhide' class='changepasswordfield'>
            <a href='#'>Change password ?</a>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div id='showhide' class='addcontactinfofield'>
            <a href='#'>Add Contact info</a>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: use unique id.. dont use same name

Comment: var cls = document.getElementById('showhide').className; // Wrong use of statement
.Use var cls = document.getElementById('showhide');

Comment: I think you've mixed the `id` and `class` attributes: `id` should be unique, `class` is for styling+organization.

Comment: As stated by @Kroltan your DIV Ids must be unique. Use a common class for the 2 elements and use a jQuery class selector `$(".your-class")`.

Comment: you are using "showhide" id twise which is duplicate, make sure that we should not use duplicate element id in document other wise first element always triggerd, we can use duplicate class and other attributes.

Answer (score 3):

**IDs in HTML must be unique**, You should use `data-` prefixed custom HTML attributes to store information

*HTML*, Here added a common class

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class='showhide' data-id='changepasswordfield'>
            <a href='#'>Change password ?</a>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class='showhide' data-id='addcontactinfofield'>
            <a href='#'>Add Contact info</a>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

*Script*, Here used common class to bind event and use [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to fetch custom attributes values

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".showhide").click(function () {
        $("#" + $(this).data('id')).show();
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```